# Can something that "will have been done" happen before the sentence is spoken?

Tags: verbs, tenses

There is a tense (can't remember its name) where in the future, something was done. The form is "< time-in-the-future >, the < noun > will have < verb >-ed".

My question is this: might < noun > have already < verb >-ed at the time of speaking?

I would usually use this form if it will < verb > sometime before < time-in-the-future >, but I think it could be used the aforementioned way.

As a sample sentence: "tomorrow, the probe will have passed Jupiter." could it have passed yesterday?

Comment: Why don't you give us a sample sentence?

Comment: @Centaurus added one.

Comment: I would say it can; to give a related sample sentence, "The probe will have passed Jupiter by now."

Comment: I don't think so. It would be an odd and confusing usage; e.g., *"Six weeks from now, Trump will have become President of the United States." See how that is misleading?

Comment: @MarkHubbard: No; it is not misleading - although nearly anything can mislead some people some of the time. It simply means that six weeks from now it will be true that Trump is the President AND that **at some time before that** he was *not* President. It does **not** imply that he is not President when the sentence is spoken.

Comment: Hmmm. I'll have to think about that. Thank you for your comment, Drew.

Comment: It's technically ambiguous, but I think there is usually an assumption that the thing has not yet happened. Consider the statement *Five years from now, I will have turned forty*. If, in fact, I am currently forty-two (or fifty), the statement is accurate, but I think at least a little misleading.

Comment: Drew, I still think it is incorrect. Perhaps I'm being thick-headed, but I can't think of any proper example of "will have become" that isn't preceded by a prepositional phrase, especially a "by-phrase" (or perhaps an "in-phrase"). For instance, if I mailed you a letter from England last week, I could have written, "By the time you read this, Trump ***will have become*** President of the United States." (Alternatively, "will be.") But if I were writing to you today, I'd have to say, "Six weeks from now, Trump ***will have been*** President of the United States for six weeks and two days." No??

Comment: this extended discussion is what has been going on in my head.

Comment: Perhaps an example is "In 10 years, I will have been over 40 for 12 years."

(a contrived and unlikely example, to be sure)